# Why are cohomotopy groups defined only up to dimension $2m-2$ and not $2m-1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The addition in $\pi^m(X)=[X,S^m]$ is defined as follows. Choose representants $\alpha, \beta$ of $[\alpha], [\beta]\in \pi^m(S)$ and let $(\alpha, \beta): X\to S^m\times S^m$. If $\mathrm{dim} X<2n$, there exists a map $X\to S^m\vee S^m$ homotopic to $(\alpha,\beta)$ by the cellular approximation theorem and composing it with the folding map we get a representant $X\to S^m$ of the $\pi^m$-sum of $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$.

Is there a simple explanation why this construction works only up to dimension $2m-2$? Is there a problem with commutativity in dimension $2m-1$? I cannot see what fails in *Hu: Homotopy Theory* if $X$ has dimension $2m-1$, that is, $(X,A)$ is only "$2m$-coconnected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the extra dimension for the homotopy between any two choices of maps $X\to S^m\vee S^m$! In more detail:

The composition should be well-defined. If $f,f':X\to S^m\vee S^m$ are two choices for $(\alpha,\beta)$, you need to prove that composition with the folding map gives the same element in $[X,S^m]$. To do this, you have to exhibit a homotopy between $f$ and $f'$. There exists a homotopy between them only once you compose with $S^m\vee S^m\to S^m\times S^m$.

By definition, the homotopy is a map $X\times I\to S^m\times S^m$. Taking the product with $I$ increases the dimension by one, so to use cellular approximation of maps to obtain a homotopy $X\times I\to S^m\vee S^m$ between $f$ and $f'$, you actually need to assume $\dim X\leq 2m-2$.